# Does elementary OS support tablet input (for writing)?

Tags: hardware, input, internationalization

I see that there is built-in support for Wacom, but I wonder if Elementary OS supports tablets for writing (there aren't many distros that I know of support this).

I installed elementary OS for my grandparents, but realized only after that they can't use the tablet input they're used to anymore.

We're Chinese, and to comfortably type in Chinese with a keyboard requires mastery of Pinyin (the Chinese alphabet), which most elderly people struggle with. Thus they need a tablet that converts their strokes to characters and input them in the system.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**, nothing like this is built into elementary OS or Ubuntu. If you'd like to request the feature more prominently, try [filing a wishlist request in the bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+filebug) or [creating a developer bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/bounties).

The best handwriting recognition program I found was [**CellWriter**](http://risujin.org/cellwriter/): **`sudo apt install cellwriter`**

(You may need to install the universe repo if it isn't already active: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.) If you give it a try, let us know how it goes? ([Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1zl18j/are_there_good_handwriting_recognition_programs/?ref=share&ref_source=link) are some others.)